# How to remove title, share button, youtube logo from videojs

Tags: reactjs, typescript, youtube, video.js

I'm using videojs to render youtube videos.
But I can't remove the video title, share button or youtube logo.

My videojs config:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    if (videoNode.current) {
      const playerInstance = videojs(videoNode.current, {
        ...initialOptions,
        ...options,
        BlockYoutubeButton: false,
      });

      setPlayer(playerInstance);
    }
  }, [videoNode?.current, options]);
```

Options:

```
const videoJsOptions = {
    ...optionsPlayer,
    playing: true,
    sources: [
      {
        type: "video/youtube",
        src: optionsPlayer.urlVideoTY
          ? optionsPlayer.urlVideoTY
          : "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hzqmRq56X8o",
      },
    ],
    techOrder: ["youtube"],
  };
```

can someone help me to remove the buttons?
Thank you very much

I've already tried adding the css to override the class and adding `diplay:none`, but I can't access the iframe either.
I already tried to add the parameter: `controls: false` and `controlBar: false` in the videojs options, but it didn't work either

Answer (score 0):

You can't... when you use [videojs-youtube](https://github.com/videojs/videojs-youtube), You Tube's player is used with a *reduced* UI, with Video.js's UI and API on top. You Tube will always show some of its UI.